# query with logical and operator in mongodb in version prior to version 2

Tags: mongodb

Could you please tell, if something like this:

```
db.subscribers.find({ LISTID: 59,  {$and : [ {field: { $in: ['English', 'Spanish']} }, 
                                             {field: {$nin: ['Chinese']}}] }}
```

can be rewritten to work in mongodb versions before 2? Or it's impossible make such query in these versions.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: It says that $and operator is only in mongodb v2.0+. I thought maybe it can be written somehow in previous versions.

Comment: It's possible to upgrade I guess. On server I have v2.04, but my localhost I have 1.6. I simply wonder if such query can be made in 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have read in the documentation, this operator is v2.0+ only. So, in previous versions it simply didn't exist.

You can either upgrade your mongod, or take the source and implement the operator yourself.

Comment: I corrected to more query that makes sense. It works in v2, but doesn't work in 1.6.

Comment: 1.6 is ancient. Why do you still use it?

Comment: It's possible to upgrade I guess. On server I have v2.04, but my localhost I have 1.6. I simply wonder if such query can be made in 1.6.

Comment: Isn't it possible to make such query in version 1.6?